# Cannot return row count after firebase data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I am trying to display different data in a tableView, according to what type of user is logged in. If the `typeOfUser` is set to admin, it should display certain data. If it is anything else, it should display something else.

I get the error `Unexpected non-void return value in void function` on return lines inside the `if typeOfUser == "admin"`.

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            let user = Auth.auth().currentUser!
            ref.child("users").child(user.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // Get user value
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let typeOfUser = value?["typeOfUser"] as? String ?? ""

                if typeOfUser == "admin" {
                    return self.loggedInAdminsMenu.count // ERROR HERE
                } else {
                    return self.loggedInMenu.count // ERROR HERE
                }

            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        } else {
            return notLoggedInMenu.count
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you aren't returning from your function, you are returning from the closure `observeSingleEvent` which is a void function. Instead, you can execute the code in `viewDidLoad` and instead of returning, you can assign the value to a variable and call `tableView.reloadData()`. Don't forget to also change the `numberOfRows(inSection:)` function to return this newly created variable.

Answer (score 1):

Another Approach would be to call a **function with a closure** in view did load which returns you the appropriate menu count. Then reload the table view. This way is more **clean** and **reusable**.

Function

```
private func getMenuCountByUser(completion: @escaping (Int) ->() ) {
//your code of getting type of user
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
  let user = Auth.auth().currentUser!
  ref.child("users").child(user.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    // Get user value
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let typeOfUser = value?["typeOfUser"] as? String ?? ""

    if typeOfUser == "admin" {

      //return self.loggedInAdminsMenu.count // Change HERE
      completion(self.loggedInAdminsMenu.count)
    } else {
      //return self.loggedInMenu.count // Change HERE
      completion( return self.loggedInMenu.count)
    }

  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
```

Then in your **viewDidLoad**

```
getMenuCountByUser { (menuCountFromClosue) in
  //reload tableView
  self.menuCount = menuCountFromClosue
  tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Note**: self.**menuCount** is a variable which will be given to table view numberOfRowsInASection

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
  return self.menuCount
}
```

Hope it helps